# I am trying to to add a list of numbers using LISP basic functions and recursion of a lambda function

Tags: recursion, lambda, lisp

Here is my code so far.

```
(defun myReduce (foo L)
        (if(eq L nil)
        nil
        (if(eq (car(cdr L)) nil)
               nil
        (cons (funcall foo(car L) (car(cdr L)))
                        (myReduce foo (cdr(cdr L)))))))))
```

it return a list ( 3 7 )
*** here is my trace***

```
``>(trace myReduce)

(MYREDUCE)

>(myReduce (lambda (x y) (+ x y)) '(1 2 3 4 5))

  1> (MYREDUCE (SYSTEM:LAMBDA-CLOSURE () () () (X Y) (+ X Y))
         (1 2 3 4 5))
    2> (MYREDUCE (SYSTEM:LAMBDA-CLOSURE () () () (X Y) (+ X Y))
           (3 4 5))
      3> (MYREDUCE (SYSTEM:LAMBDA-CLOSURE () () () (X Y) (+ X Y)) (5))
      <3 (MYREDUCE NIL)
    <2 (MYREDUCE (7))
  <1 (MYREDUCE (3 7))
(3 7)``
```

I have tried to do this(updated code) ...

```
(defun myReduce (foo L)
        (if(eq L nil)
        nil
        (if(eq (car(cdr L)) nil)
               nil
        (+ (cons (funcall foo(car L) (car(cdr L)))
                        (myReduce foo (cdr(cdr L))))))))))
```

to get the program to add the recursive list to the `cons` list but to no avail,
***here is the trace to the updated code***

```
>(trace myReduce)

(MYREDUCE)

>(myReduce (lambda (x y) (+ x y)) '(1 2 3 4 5))

  1> (MYREDUCE (SYSTEM:LAMBDA-CLOSURE () () () (X Y) (+ X Y))
         (1 2 3 4 5))
    2> (MYREDUCE (SYSTEM:LAMBDA-CLOSURE () () () (X Y) (+ X Y))
           (3 4 5))
      3> (MYREDUCE (SYSTEM:LAMBDA-CLOSURE () () () (X Y) (+ X Y)) (5))
      <3 (MYREDUCE NIL)

Error: TYPE-ERROR :DATUM (7) :EXPECTED-TYPE NUMBER
Fast links are on: do (si::use-fast-links nil) for debugging
Signalled by +.
TYPE-ERROR :DATUM (7) :EXPECTED-TYPE NUMBER
```

can anyone lead me in a good orderly direction?

Comment: Your code does not look like indented correctly. You might want to improve that.

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` has lots of features but without the keywords it does `(+ 5 (+ 4 (+ 3 (+ 2 1))))` for `(reduce #'+ '(1 2 3 4 5))`. There is not `cons` whatsoever. Here is a simpler version from Scheme called `foldl`:

```
(defun foldl (fun initial-value lst)
  (labels ((helper (init lst)
             (if lst
                 (helper (funcall fun (car lst) init) (cdr lst))
                 init)))
    (helper initial-value lst)))

(foldl #'cons '() '(1 2 3))
; ==> (3 2 1)
```

`reduce` mimics this if you pass `initial-value` as a keyword parameter. `reduce` replaced a large set of similar functions and is not as trivial to implement. eg. how it's behaving with an empty list and one element list without `initial-value` is quite special.